# Сигнатура <bool(int)> с использованием std::placeholders::_2

Tags: c++

Изучал лекцию по стандартной библиотеке С++ и возник вопрос. Хочу поддержать сигнатуру функционального объекта  для ф-ии lessThan:

```
bool lessThan(int v, int max)
{
    return v < max;
}
```

Однако, хочу попробовать подставить аргумент с помощью std::bind на первое место (число 4), оставив для ввода второй аргумент std::placeholder::_2. Для этого создаю функциональный объект foo и инициализирую его:

```
using foo = std::function<bool (int)>;
foo moreThan4 = std::bind(lessThan, 4, _2); // Ошибка
```

Однако при подобной инициализации с помощью bind происходит ошибка. Подскажите, возможно ли подставить аргумент на первое место и вызывать ф-ю с помощью одного аргумента, чтобы он подставлялся на второе место?

Comment: `std::bind(lessThan, 4, std::placeholders::_1);`

Comment: Так значит std::placeholders::_n означает не n-ый номер параметра, а кол-во вводимых параметров, верно?

Comment: @Chudvan скорее порядковый номер. Т.е. первый переданный аргумент будет подставлен туда, где находится _1. Например, можно поменять местами аргументы: `auto foo = std::bind(lessThan, _2, _1);` тогда вызов `foo(4, 5)` приведет к вызову `lessThan(5, 4)`

Comment: `_n` - это номер параметра функтора, а позиция - это место вставки этого параметра при вызове обернутой функйии